# How many bytes are used by variable in hexadecimal?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am currently studying for a test and I came across this question and for some reason I seem to be having a hard time with it and I was hoping I could get some clarification here.

I found an answer on yahoo answers but it came with no explanation and I don't really believe thats the answer. It simply states that 0040006Ah - 00400020h = 4A = 74 bytes.

The question is this: 
**The address of var1 is 00400020h. The address of the next variable after var1 is 0040006Ah. How many bytes are used by var1?**

Please correct me if I'm wrong but it is to my understanding that each "digit" represented by a hexadecimal value contains 4 bits. So if my understanding of the question is correct, the answer should be less then a byte. Since the difference of 4A does not equate to a byte. The difference has to be at least FFh to count as a byte. Please correct me or point me in a right direction if I am wrong

Comment: I made a mistake, its 74 not 72 but is my question not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each address is a separate byte.  Memory is byte-addressable.  i.e. `0x0040006A` is the address of a whole byte.

`0040006Ah - 00400020h` is a difference in address of 0x4A = 74, which means a difference of 74 bytes.

Addresses in asm map 1:1 with `char *` in C, on normal machines.  (This is not guaranteed by the C standard, this is just a fact of normal C implementations).

Comment: Ah i see, so if i understand this correctly now. Each of the address point to a byte stored in memory. 0040006Ah is just a container for "pointers". In our example case, our machine holds (16^8 - 1) unique address?

Comment: @EdwardLim: Yes, but it's not a "container for pointers".  0040006Ah *is* a pointer value.  If addresses are 32-bit, then there are 2^32 different ones possible.  (Remember that 0 is a possible address.  2^32 - 1 is the highest one, though.)